# AWS Lambda taking so long to execute (cold start) with Spring Cloud

Tags: performance, aws-lambda, java-8, aws-api-gateway, spring-cloud

There is a requirement where we are trying to convert the existing Spring boot rest API to AWS serverless architecture.

Below is architecture we are following.

> API Gateway --> AWS Lambda --> Postgres DB (local EC2 instance)

In the API Gateway, we have created a REST API setup and we have integrated our lambda to that API.

In the Lambda, we have used Spring Cloud with Java-8 and it is furthur connecting with PostgresDB for the Crud operations using Spring Data JPA.

## Probelm :

if we talk about the Lambda then it is working fine as per expected. Like Spring projects get started and it will do the work as expected but the problem is because Spring Cloud has some internal extra dependencies so because of that Lambda Size become approx. 40-50 MB and it is taking more than 30 seconds to respond. Because of this API Gateway gives Gateway Timeout as the max timeout setup on API Gateway is 30 seconds.

As per the analysis, we observed that AWS lambda always starting the complete Spring project and also creating connection with DB which is a time consuming part.

As an end-user it is not a good experience because API is taking so long to respond which it should not take.

Can anyone help me understand what we are doing wrong on the Infra side or on Java (Spring Cloud) side ?

How we can reduce the Lambda execution time ? How we can cache the Database connection or any other java stuff caching so that lambda will be faster and response time of the API gets reduced.

TIA

Answer (score 3):

This is a question with a large scope. Therefore, I won't be able to give you a detailed answer.

But here are a few suggestions (links at the bottom):

1. Investigate AWS SnapStart. It is a new feature announced at re:Invent 2022 that works only with Java applications at the moment and is supposed to reduce cold starts. They even have Spring examples.
2. Consider switching to RDS to be able to use AWS Lambda RDS Proxy. This could reduce database latency.
3. Spring Native images. Apparently, you can use GraalVM to create "native" Java images to run on AWS Lambda. I have never tried it, but it might be a good option to investigate.

Apart from this I am not sure that there are a lot of things that you could do. There is always the possibility to keep your Lambdas "hot", so there is no cold start but then you are losing most of the benefits of Lambda, so I do not consider this to be an adequate solutions.

If you are really serious of working a lot with AWS Lambda, I would also recommend re-thinking using Java. It is a great language that has a lot of merit, but it is not as well suited to AWS Lambda. The best two options I found over the years is either Go or pure Javascript (no Typescript). Obviously, opinions will be different and different developments like SnapStart will help, but I am not sure that they are worth all the trouble.

**Links**

1. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-accelerate-your-lambda-functions-with-lambda-snapstart/
2. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/
3. https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/how-to-keep-your-lambda-functions-warm
4. https://effectiveserverless.com/spring-boot-native-graalvm-lambda